# Wire Wrapping - power + ground

Tags: layout

I'm interested in getting into experimenting with wire wrapping for some small microcontroller projects using some Arduino Nanos.

I've watched a bunch of videos online, but something that is not explained is - **how do you handle power and ground when wire wrapping?**

Do you chain all your pins that use power or ground point-to-point?  Or do you create some sort of bus that runs near certain components that you tie into?

I found this image: [image: Bil Herd Wire Wrap example] in a [Hack-a-Day post](http://hackaday.com/2014/12/18/wire-wrap-101/) by Bil Herd which shows some designs he wrapped.  I noticed the thick black wires that run along the board, which I believe are for power.  On the opposite side of the board, he appears to have a bare-wire ground wire:[image: Bil Herd Wire Wrap example 2]

This looks handy - but I'm not sure how you tie into those wires since you can't wrap onto them.  It's not clear to me from the picture as to how they connect to the wire wrap pins.  I believe the T-bits that go from the ground on top of the board to the bottom are soldered.

I had a thought of taking some male headers that have wire-wrap length pins on both sides of the plastic bit in the middle and just wrapping all of the pins on one side together to make a ground or power strip.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've wire-wrapped onto round leads before. It takes a bit of strength and care, but it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Almost a shopping question, so am not going to address a possible source for this kind of universal wire-wrap breadboard. The bus under the chips could be ground, while the bus between the chips might be +supply. Note that **this example is not wire-wrap** but a close cousin. I think it was called "slit-and-wrap".
The breadboard can handle both standard-width chips (0.3" and 0.6"). I might strip all the insulation from a grounded connection, solder it to the adjacent ground bus, then wrap it. This builder appears to have soldered each wire-wrap post to the breadboard - not a good plan unless you must connect other passive components like resistors, capacitors to a post.
[image: almost wire-wrap breadboard]

Comment: only bundle synchronous signals and not async signals if doing more than this to avoid crosstalk. If critical signals use twisted pair.  Proto boards like this use wide conductors to lower inductance proportionally. Be sure to wrap 1 turn of insulation for strength from sharp bends.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Good points, all. Also, learn to strip without nicking the wire.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just bend over the GND lead of the socket, and solder directly to the Thick GND wire. Ditto for the VDD lead.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to make the connections to the pins in any significantly different way with power and ground wires when wire-wrapping, just make sure there is sufficient wire there going in the right directions.

The easiest, and usually completely adequate way, is to grid the power and ground. Run a set of wires north-south connecting to every ground in columns. Then run a set of wires east-west, connecting to the same grounds in rows. This will ensure that return current due to any signal will be able to find a reasonably close return path. Do the same for power.